# Converting ntext to varchar in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to convert from ntext to varchar in SQL Server?

This is the syntax: ALTER TABLE TBL1 ALTER COLUMN email varchar NULL.

**This is the error message:**
Cannot alter column 'email' because it is 'ntext'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to convert the column to bare `varchar` - without a length parameter, it defaults to `varchar(1)` - possibly the most pointless datatype in existence.

Comment: Does `ALTER TABLE TBL1 ALTER COLUMN email nvarchar (max)` work? (Does for me on SQL Server 2008)

Comment: @Martin It works fine, I tested it although in Sql Server 2008 but I think it's possible in Sql Server 2005 either.

Comment: @Jani - Tested on SQL Server 2005 and couldn't reproduce either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you definitely on SQL Server 2005 - Not 2000?

I tested the following and couldn't get the same error message as you

```
CREATE TABLE TBL1
(
email NTEXT NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO TBL1 VALUES (N'ghfhfhgtf') 


ALTER TABLE TBL1 ALTER COLUMN email varchar NULL
/*Error: String or binary data would be truncated.*/

ALTER TABLE TBL1 ALTER COLUMN email nvarchar (max)
/*Works*/
```